# Upgrading Android Firebase Libraries Causes Crash

Tags: java, android, firebase, build.gradle, android-manifest

I'm looking at upgrading my firebase libraries within my application, however once I upgrade them to the latest versions, I consistently get a crash when starting the application. The log shows

```
2019-02-01 13:29:28.845 com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
    com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.b.g: Error reading from input stream
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.a.a(SourceFile:28)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.j.b.run(SourceFile:15)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6)
     Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.f(SourceFile:103)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.au.read(SourceFile:2)
        at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ao.run(SourceFile:18)
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.an.run(SourceFile:2)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:457) 
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:14) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.bl.run(SourceFile:4) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764) 
        at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ai.run(SourceFile:6)
```

Here is the build.gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.25.4'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.application.id“
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27

        // Enabling multidex support.
        multiDexEnabled true
        dexOptions {
            javaMaxHeapSize "2048M"
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    //compile project(':volley')
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'
...
    implementation 'commons-io:commons-io:2.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'

    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The libraries which I updated are

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:15.0.1'`
to
`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:17.1.0'`

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:15.0.2'` to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.7'`

`implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:15.0.2'` to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'`

and `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:15.0.1'` to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.1.3'`

Why could these updates be causing the crash?

Comment: does this app uses the microphone and is running on your emulator?

Comment: The microphone is used within the app, and within the Manifest file I do have `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>`

Comment: yes but the emulator does not have that piece of hardware, and if you are running this in your emulator, that might be the problem, did you tried it in a real device?

Comment: Testing on a physical device actually gave some more information on the problem. Looking into it there were updates for AdMob initialization starting with version 17.0.0, and there needed to be some updates within the Manifest file for that. Once that was updated, the application now loads on both the emulators and physical devices.